# invoke subscribe on 2nd observable based on the value of the first

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I need to make 2 API calls, first one will always execute and return a true or false.  2nd one should only call subscribe if the 1st one returned true.

Is there an Rxjs operator I can use for this, rather than putting a subscribe within a subscribe?

I've used switchmap when invoking 2 subscribes, but in that scenario i passed the result from the 1st to the 2nd and 2nd always had to execute.

Here I want to avoid the 2nd call if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this article.

https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/rxjs-iif-operator-ternary-operator-under-the-hood-148b28e752e4

OR

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif

RXJS **"IFF"** Operator provide an ternary operator kind of behavior.

```
firstCall(args).pipe(
   iif(res => res===true,secondCall(otherArgs),EMPTY),
).subscribe(doStuff);
```

Answer (score 1):

IMK there is no rxjs operator as such, this more of a custom application need, you will have to write your own logic for this. Do this logic by piping the observable rather than by subscribing multiple times.

```
firstApiCall('url').pipe(
   mergeMap((data) => {  // your flattening operator
      if (data) {
        return secondApiCall('url')
      }
      return of(data)
   }
)).subscribe((data) => {
     console.log(data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `filter` before `switchMap`.

```
firstCall(args).pipe(
   filter(res => res === true),
   switchMap(() => secondCall(otherArgs),
).subscribe(doStuff);
```

Comment: IMK, adding a filter will not let the control go the subscribe (in falsy conditions), coz we are filtering the stream out.